# How to disable or avoid the language translation option on Android webview?

Tags: android, webview, translate

I'd like to embed a webwiew in my app, but I would like to avoid the language translate option that sometimes appears when loading a web.
I've seen that if you are browsing whit Chrome there is a setting option to disable (http://en.kioskea.net/faq/12336-google-chrome-disable-the-translation-of-foreign-language-websites), but I haven't founded that setting in Android web view to disable it by code (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html). 
May be it is no possible.

Thank you for any help

Comment: As far as I know that is a feature of chrome. A webview wouldn't even have that translation option so you should be fine

Comment: When I load a web in the webview  the translate dialog appears, so it has that feature, although I don`t know if it is possible to handle it by code. Thanks.

Comment: Surely you're right Ivo, I think that the web is loading in the browser. Thank you.